# Unable to publish updates on Itunes connect after Mac OS update

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator

from today ( 20 /01 /2016 )

if i try to publish a new update for all of my apps
in the Itunes connect i have this error

"Le nuove app e i rispettivi aggiornamenti devono includere le versioni pubbliche (GM) di Xcode 6 o successive, OS X e iOS SDK. Non inviare le app sviluppate con software beta, incluse le build beta di OS X. "

"New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of xCode”

but I'm already on the last stable xCode and Mac OS (updated today)

Comment: This is not a titanium issue, but this is an xCode version. Are you sure you're not on a downloaded xCode version (outside of the app store)?

Comment: yes im sure, i deleted and downloaded again from appstore to be sure
i want to know if other have the same problem

Comment: do you not have any other versions installed, and have you made a new build with the newly downloaded xcode?

Comment: Weird, Apple didn't announce they dropped Xcode 6 yet: https://developer.apple.com/news/

Comment: Could you check your build logs (use `-l trace` for more detail) to double check which path to Xcode Titanium uses to build? And then open that Xcode to see what version it is?

Comment: same issue here? Have you solved? I'm trying to upgrade my OS beta to last release.